# PHP / Laravel - One Model with multiple polymorphic relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my web app, users will be able to save some parsed content to a table called `field_results`.

However, this model needs to reference two polymorphic relationships:

`FieldResults.php`:

```
    // A field result morphs to either a document field or email field.
    public function fieldable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    // A field result morphs to either a document or email.
    public function typeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

The `fieldable` refers to:

1. DocumentFields
2. EmailFields

and the `typeable` refers to:

1. Documents
2. Emails

In my `DocumentField` and `EmailField` models, I have defined this relationship:

```
    // A field will have a final result.
    public function result()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(FieldResult::class, 'fieldable');
    }
```

And in my `Document` and `Email` models, I have defined this:

```
public function results()
{
    return $this->morphMany(FieldRuleResult::class, 'typeable');
}
```

So consider below loop, where I need to save some content, that will reference a specific documentfield/emailfield and a specific document/email.

```
     foreach ($document->fields as $field) {
         $content = $field->content->text;

         //Save the content to `FieldResult
         $field->result()->create(['content' => $content]);
     }
```

Above will only set the values for the `fieldable` morph:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 : Field 'typeable_type' doesn't have a default value [...]
```

If I change it to save to the document instead, I get below error::

```
//Save the content to `FieldResult
 $document->result()->create(['content' => $content]);
```

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]:  General error: 1364 Field 'fieldable_type' doesn't have a default value [...]
```

How can I do, so my model `FieldResult` can have two polymorphic relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by replacing this line:

`$field->result()->create(['content' => $content]);`

By the following lines:

```
$field->result()->create([
  'content' => $content,
  'typeable_id' => $document->id,
  'typeable_type' => get_class($document),
]);
```